# com.android.build.api.transform.TransfromException:java.util.zip.ZipException:duplicate entry:android/support/v4/view/MotionCompactEclair.class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-api

The code is giving an error of duplicate entry. Didn't understand the duplicates files in my project.
Also deleted all the duplicates file and also enabled mutltidex but still can't fix the error.

The gradle file is givin below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.codehacker.pocketambulance"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    multiDexEnabled=true;
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.3-sources.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.12.0-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-jackson-1.16.0-rc.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

The manifest file is givin below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.codehacker.pocketambulance">

<uses-permission      android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I also cleaned my project but still getting the same error
The error is given below

```
Error:Execution failed for task    ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:    java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:    android/support/v4/view/MotionEventCompatEclair.class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify gradle file like this:

```
android {
    ...

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
```